# How to remove specific <options> in different <select> with remove()?

Tags: jquery, html-select

I would like to do with my script on Jquery but I totally don't know how to do it. =/
So, my problem actually is that I don't know at all, for example, when I remove a Book, which contains Chapter blocks inside. Well the option of the book in the select tag #whichBook removed too, but not all the options of the chapters associated to it in the select tag #whichChapter.

SO, what i want to know it's :  How when I press the button .removeBook for example, then have all the options from the select #whichChapter related to the .BookName which I just removed, then removed too (like the .ChapterName  removed).

I was thinking to something and try something here, but's that's dont really work : =/

```
$(document).on('click', '.removeBook', function(){
var BOOK = $(this).closest('.BookName' ).attr('data-book-name');
$('#whichBook option:contains("'+ BOOK +'")').remove();
var CHAPTER = $(document).closest('.ChapterName' ).attr('data-chapter-name');
$('#whichChapter option:contains("'+ CHAPTER +'")').remove();
```

});

So here is my code on Fiddle, thanks you so much in advance if you can solve my problem. As i begin JQuery, I have not yet a great knowledge about it.

Post Script : I have another problem with a conflict when the name of two books or two chapters or two lines have the same name, but that's not actually the principal problem =)

```js
//Remove Buttons - Function ////START////
$("#list").on('click', "button.removeBook", function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
});

$("#list").on('click', "button.removeChapter", function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
});

$("#list").on('click', "button.removeLine", function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
});

$(document).on('click', '.removeBook', function() {
  var BOOK = $(this).closest('.BookName').attr('data-book-name');
  $('#whichBook option:contains("' + BOOK + '")').remove();
  var CHAPTER = $(document).closest('.ChapterName').attr('data-chapter-name');
  $('#whichChapter option:contains("' + CHAPTER + '")').remove();
});

$(document).on('click', '.removeChapter', function() {
  var CHAPTER = $(this).closest('.ChapterName').attr('data-chapter-name');
  $('#whichChapter option:contains("' + CHAPTER + '")').remove();
});
//Remove Buttons - Function ////END////

//SlideToggle Forms - Function ////START////
$("#select").change(function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  $("#select-choice > div").hide();
  $("." + val).slideToggle();
});
//SlideToggle Forms - Function ////END////

//Append generated elements- Function ////START////
//FOR BOOK
$('#createBook').click(function() {
  var listItem = $('#bookName').val();
  //Create a select option in <select id="#whichBook">
  $("#whichBook").append('<option>' + $('#bookName').val() + '</option>');

  //Create a <div class="BookName"> in <div id="list">
  $('#list').append('<div class="BookName" data-book-name="' + $('#bookName').val().replace(/ /g, "-") + '">' + listItem + '<button type="button" name="removeBook" class="removeBook">Remove</button>' + '</div>');
  $('#bookName').val('');
});

//FOR CHAPTER
$('#createChapter').click(function() {
  //Create a select option in <select id="#whichChapter"> if at least one <div class="BookName"> exist
  if ($('.BookName').length > 0) {
    $("#whichChapter").append('<option>' + $('#chapterName').val() + '</option>');
    var listItem = $('#chapterName').val();
    var bookName = $('#whichBook option:selected').val().replace(/ /g, "-");

    //Create a <div class="ChapterName"> inside the <div class="BookName"> associated with the <select id="#whichBook"> if at least one <div class="BookName"> exist.

    $('.BookName[data-book-name=' + bookName + ']', '#list').append('<div class= "ChapterName" data-chapter-name="' + $('#chapterName').val().replace(/ /g, "-") + '">' + '>' + listItem + '<button type="button" name="v" class="removeChapter">Remove</button>' + '</div>');
    //$( ".ChapterName").data("bookName") === $('#chapterName').val();
  }
});

//FOR LINE
$('#createLine').click(function() {
  //Create a select option in <select id="#whichLine"> (which don't really exist) if at least one <div class="ChapterName"> exist.
  if ($('.ChapterName').length > 0) {
    $("#whichLine").append('<option>' + $('#lineName').val() + '</option>');
    var listItem = $('#lineName').val();
    var chapterName = $('#whichChapter option:selected').val().replace(/ /g, "-");

    //Create a <div class="ChapterName"> inside the <div class="BookName"> associated with the <select id="#whichBook"> if at least one <div class="BookName"> exist.

    $('.ChapterName[data-chapter-name=' + chapterName + ']', '#list').append('<div class= "LineName" data-list-name="' + $('#lineName').val().replace(/ /g, "-") + '">' + '>' + '>' + listItem + '<button type="button" name="removeLine" class="removeLine">Remove</button>' + '</div>');
    //$( ".ChapterName").data("bookName") === $('#chapterName').val();
  }
});

//Append generated elements- Function ////END////
```

```css
#select-choice>div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select">
  <option value="none">Select something</option>
  <option value="book">a Book</option>
  <option value="chapter">a Chapter</option>
  <option value="line">a Line</option>
</select>

<div id="select-choice">

  <div class="book">
    <input type="text" id="bookName" name="name" placeholder="Book Name">
    <button type="button" name="createBook" id="createBook">Create</button>
  </div>

  <div class="chapter">
    <select id="whichBook">
      <option value="none">From which book?</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="chapterName" name="name" placeholder="Chapter Name">
    <button type="button" name="createChapter" id="createChapter">Create</button>
  </div>

  <div class="line">
    <select id="whichChapter">
      <option value="none">From which chapter?</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="lineName" name="name" placeholder="Line Name">
    <button type="button" name="createLine" id="createLine">Create</button>
  </div>

</div>
<hr>
<div class="optionBox">
  <div id="list"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you clarify a little what exactly is your question here?

Comment: @Sami Sure I will re-edit my post to be more clear but what I want to know it's how when i press the button .removeBook for example, to have all the options from the select #whichChapter related to the .BookName which I just removed, then removed too (like the .ChapterName <div> removed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
//Remove Buttons - Function ////START////
$("#list").on('click', "button.removeBook", function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
});

$("#list").on('click', "button.removeChapter", function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
});

$("#list").on('click', "button.removeLine", function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
});

$(document).on('click', '.removeBook', function() {
  var BOOK = $(this).closest('.BookName').attr('data-book-name');
  $('#whichBook option:contains("' + BOOK + '")').remove();
  var CHAPTER = $(document).closest('.ChapterName').attr('data-chapter-name');
  $('#whichChapter option[data-book-name="' + BOOK + '"]').remove();
});

$(document).on('click', '.removeChapter', function() {
  var CHAPTER = $(this).closest('.ChapterName').attr('data-chapter-name');
  $('#whichChapter option:contains("' + CHAPTER + '")').remove();
});
//Remove Buttons - Function ////END////

//SlideToggle Forms - Function ////START////
$("#select").change(function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  $("#select-choice > div").hide();
  $("." + val).slideToggle();
});
//SlideToggle Forms - Function ////END////

//Append generated elements- Function ////START////
//FOR BOOK
$('#createBook').click(function() {
  var listItem = $('#bookName').val();
  //Create a select option in <select id="#whichBook">
  $("#whichBook").append('<option data-book-name="' + listItem + '">' + $('#bookName').val() + '</option>' );

  //Create a <div class="BookName"> in <div id="list">
  $('#list').append('<div class="BookName" data-book-name="' + $('#bookName').val().replace(/ /g, "-") + '">' + listItem + '<button type="button" name="removeBook" class="removeBook">Remove</button>' + '</div>');
  $('#bookName').val('');
});

//FOR CHAPTER
$('#createChapter').click(function() {
  //Create a select option in <select id="#whichChapter"> if at least one <div class="BookName"> exist
  if ($('.BookName').length > 0) {
    
    var listItem = $('#chapterName').val();
    var bookName = $('#whichBook option:selected').val().replace(/ /g, "-");
$("#whichChapter").append('<option data-book-name="' + bookName + '">' + $('#chapterName').val() + '</option>');
    //Create a <div class="ChapterName"> inside the <div class="BookName"> associated with the <select id="#whichBook"> if at least one <div class="BookName"> exist.

    $('.BookName[data-book-name=' + bookName + ']', '#list').append('<div class= "ChapterName" data-chapter-name="' + $('#chapterName').val().replace(/ /g, "-") + '">' + '>' + listItem + '<button type="button" name="v" class="removeChapter">Remove</button>' + '</div>');
    //$( ".ChapterName").data("bookName") === $('#chapterName').val();
  }
});

//FOR LINE
$('#createLine').click(function() {
  //Create a select option in <select id="#whichLine"> (which don't really exist) if at least one <div class="ChapterName"> exist.
  if ($('.ChapterName').length > 0) {
    $("#whichLine").append('<option>' + $('#lineName').val() + '</option>');
    var listItem = $('#lineName').val();
    var chapterName = $('#whichChapter option:selected').val().replace(/ /g, "-");

    //Create a <div class="ChapterName"> inside the <div class="BookName"> associated with the <select id="#whichBook"> if at least one <div class="BookName"> exist.

    $('.ChapterName[data-chapter-name=' + chapterName + ']', '#list').append('<div class= "LineName" data-list-name="' + $('#lineName').val().replace(/ /g, "-") + '">' + '>' + '>' + listItem + '<button type="button" name="removeLine" class="removeLine">Remove</button>' + '</div>');
    //$( ".ChapterName").data("bookName") === $('#chapterName').val();
  }
});

//Append generated elements- Function ////END////
```

```css
#select-choice>div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select">
  <option value="none">Select something</option>
  <option value="book">a Book</option>
  <option value="chapter">a Chapter</option>
  <option value="line">a Line</option>
</select>

<div id="select-choice">

  <div class="book">
    <input type="text" id="bookName" name="name" placeholder="Book Name">
    <button type="button" name="createBook" id="createBook">Create</button>
  </div>

  <div class="chapter">
    <select id="whichBook">
      <option value="none">From which book?</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="chapterName" name="name" placeholder="Chapter Name">
    <button type="button" name="createChapter" id="createChapter">Create</button>
  </div>

  <div class="line">
    <select id="whichChapter">
      <option value="none">From which chapter?</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="lineName" name="name" placeholder="Line Name">
    <button type="button" name="createLine" id="createLine">Create</button>
  </div>

</div>
<hr>
<div class="optionBox">
  <div id="list"></div>
</div>
```

Add the same data attribute like in the divs in to the options of the select.

```
$("#whichChapter").append('<option data-book-name="' + bookName + '" >' + $('#chapterName').val() + '</option>');
```

And when you need to delete the chapters, use the data-attribute selector:

```
$(document).on('click', '.removeBook', function() {
  var BOOK = $(this).closest('.BookName').attr('data-book-name');

  $('#whichChapter option[data-book-name="' + BOOK + ']")').remove();
});
```

Snippet should have a working solution.

Comment: Thanks you so much ! =)

Comment: Glad I could help